# How to compile linux source code and make an ISO?

Tags: linux, operating-system, open-source

we have full source code of [linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) I just want know the steps to compile and and make my own version of linux. I don't want use any other code like ubuntu or Linux From Scratch, any guidance will help me allot

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 8):

Just to let you know, Linux is just a kernel, ***NOT*** a full operating system.  If you expect it to be a full operating system, you will need to also include other things like the GNU Coreutils.  Otherwise you'll be left with something almost useless to use and impossible to install on its own.

To compile the kernel, you'll need to have an existing install of some flavor of Linux (Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch, etc).

Basically, in essence, you get a copy of the Linux code, then you simply run `make`.

This is how Arch Linux builds the Linux kernel: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/linux

Comment: thanks for the info so the source code form the git hub link, what i that ? is not an os ?

Comment: It is only the kernel.  ***Linux itself is not an operating system.***  Things like Ubuntu and Arch Linux are the operating system.  They just simply use Linux for their kernel.  What you are essentially expecting to do is take something like the Darwin kernel, then making a full Mac OS X clone from just Darwin.  It doesn't work that way.